# Vert.x cluster Eventbus cross processes

Tags: cluster-computing, vert.x

Does any body have some info, links, pointer on how is cross process Eventbus communication is occurring.  Per documentation I am concluding that multiple Vert.x (thus separate JVM processes) could be clustered on and communicate via Eventbus.  However, there are little to none documentation on how to achieve it.

Looking into DOCs, I can see that  publish/registerHandler methods take address as a String what works within a process, but I can not wrap my head around on how it works cross processes and how to register and publish to address, does it work over HTTP , TCP ?   From API perspective do I need to pass port and process signature ?

Answer (score 0):

Cross process communication happens via the EventBus. Multiple vertx instances can be started up and clustered to allow separate instances on the same or other machines to communicate. The low level clustering is handled by Hazelcast.The configuration is handled by the cluster.xml file in the conf folder of your vertx install. You can learn more about the format of the file by looking at the [Hazelcast Docs](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#hazelcast-clusters). It is transparent to your handers and works over TCP.

You can test it by running two or more instances on your local machine once they are started with the -cluster flag. Look at the example being run, and the config changes required in [How to use eventbus messaging in vertx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440218/how-to-use-eventbus-messaging-in-vertx/)