# How to use eventbus messaging in vertx?

Tags: message-queue, event-bus, vert.x

I followed the instructions in [sample](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/ruby/README.md#eventbus-point-to-point) and ran:

```
vertx run eventbus_pointtopoint/receiver.rb -cluster
vertx run eventbus_pointtopoint/sender.rb -cluster
```

Then I only got:

```
➜  ruby  vertx run eventbus_pointtopoint/receiver.rb -cluster
Starting clustering...
No cluster-host specified so using address 192.168.56.1
Succeeded in deploying verticle

➜  ruby  vertx run eventbus_pointtopoint/sender.rb -cluster
Starting clustering...
No cluster-host specified so using address 192.168.56.1
Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

But no message received. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see how event bus messaging works you can just move both pieces of code into the one file and run it.

```
require "vertx"
include Vertx

EventBus.register_handler('ping-address') do |msg|
  puts "Received message: #{msg.body}"
  # Now reply to it
  msg.reply('pong!')
end

Vertx::set_periodic(1000) do
  EventBus.send('ping-address', 'ping') do |reply|
    puts "Received reply: #{reply.body}"
  end
end
```

**To run clustered**

If you want to run the example specified with clustering you may need to change your cluster.xml config file, it is in the conf folder of your vertx install. I had to change two lines, first change

```
<multicast enabled="true">
```

to false:

```
<multicast enabled="false">
```

then change

```
<tcp-ip enabled="false">
```

to true

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
```

and make sure the interface tag has the correct IP address. Then the commands you specified above should run.

Comment: That's not a solution, because I want to run two separate apps.

Comment: Did you try the second suggestion so, editing the cluster.xml file? I added a bit more info to  help.

Comment: I'll check that for sure.

Comment: Many thanks! Too bad I didn't find this in docs. It this out there?